# I have a directory path malfunctioning in some computers in a python program

Tags: python, path, ioerror

So I have been building a text based game in python as a project for learning python, implementing things as I learn them, so I started getting this error in some cases, I have been developing this game on a raspberry pi, on a machine running mint 13 and on an android tablet. Lately though I rebuilt the game in python 3.3, when I did that I started getting an error when I go to open from a directory path the code is this

```
 with open('rooms/' + str(id) + '.json', 'r', ) as f:
     jsontext = f.read()
```

I store my rooms as json files in a separate folder in the same directory that the project lies in if any one would like to see how this works you can check out the project over at [www.github.com/kevin2314/TextGame](http://www.github.com/kevin2314/TextGame). On both my raspberry pi and on my mint 13 machine this code works just fine but on my android tablet, it returns an error like this

```
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "rooms/intro.json"
```

At first I thought this might have just been because it was on android and it's not specifically built for programming in python so I didn't pay much attention to it. After I released it to github though, another person had the same issue except they were using Ubuntu, So I'm at a loss as to what the issue is with the path.

If any one can shed some light on this I'd be grateful I wouldn't like to start having this problem with a lot of people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path that you are referring to is dependent on the starting directory.  You should use the  `__file__` global variable:

```
with open(os.path.join(
             os.path.dirname(__file__), 'rooms', + str(id) + '.json'),
          'r') as f:
    jsontext = f.read()
```

I would also suggestion using `os.path.join` to create the file name so that you can use the platform specific path separators.

Note that `os.curdir()` will return the location from which the program was started, not the location of the rooms.py file.

Comment: This was exactly what was needed, I need to study up more on using the os module in python, although remember from the code I gave above rooms was a directory not a file all in all it still worked the same. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

You could use os.getcwd() to find your current directory and continue from there.

Comment: I'll have to study up on this because I'm not familiar with os.cwd() but thanks for the advice!

Comment: I have already used the other suggestion as the solution to my problem but I'll vote this up for usefulness and selfless effort.